# Outlook API - Get meeting room calendar

Tags: office365, outlook-restapi, outlook-calendar

How can I get an Office365 meeting room calendar using Outlook Calendar REST API?

I can't find anything useful on the api documentation or stackoverflow..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the Outlook CalendarView API.

The endpiont is 
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users/{user mail address}/calendarview?startDateTime={start_datetime}&endDateTime={end_datetime}

Replace the {user mail address} with the meeting room address.

Find more information from 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations

Comment: True only if using an app-token (service app). Using an user token Outlook REST API so far have limitations on accessing other users calendars. Delegate access doesn't work yet, returns 401 Unauthorized - see  stackoverflow.com/questions/35976578/